# Javascript set boolean value for dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have the below code to map 
"Active" as true
and InActive as false

```
var statusJSON = {
  '- Select -' : '', 
  'Active' : true, 
  'Inactive': false
};
$.each(statusJSON, function(key, val){
  $statusFlag.append('<option value=' + val + '>' + key + '</option>');
});
```

Also I do the following on change of dropdown;

```
$("#statusFlag").change(function() {
  self.model.set({
    statusFlag: $('#statusFlag').val()
  });
});
```

Now the issue is when I submit the form, the value in `statusFlag` is submitted as string ("true" or "false"). How do I ensure that only boolean value is set for `statusFlag`?

Comment: I think for select element only string values are allowed, hence converting booleans to string. Try comparing it with string "true" or "false"

Comment: As in `statusFlag: statusJSON[$('#statusFlag').val()]`  ?

Comment: What is the meaning of submitting a boolean? If you are talking about submitting with HTTP POST, you can send only strings.

Comment: Actually there are 3 possible values in my case..."true","false" and "" ...the last if nothing is selected (- Select -)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this works but give it try

```
$("#statusFlag").change(function() {
   self.model.set({
      statusFlag: $('#statusFlag').val().toLowerCase() == "true" ? true : false
   });
});
```

Comment: Thx...But actually there are 3 possible values in my case..."true","false" and "" ...the last if nothing is selected (- Select -)

Answer (score 1):

Since the actual "value" of the element is a string, and `.val()` returns a string, to get a boolean you'll need to examine that string and return a boolean of your own.  Something like that:

```
statusFlag: $('#statusFlag').val() == 'true'
```

This should set `statusFlag` to `true` if the strings match, `false` otherwise.

> How do I *ensure* that only boolean value is set for statusFlag?

Define "ensure" in this case.  The above example will always set `statusFlag` to a boolean value because a `==` comparison always results in a boolean value.  However, other code elsewhere can set `statusFlag` to anything.  JavaScript is dynamically typed, so there's no way to *guarantee* from the property itself that it will only ever be set to a specific type.

You *could* perhaps wrap the property in a closure (making it "private") and expose a custom setter function which would internally examine whatever gets passed to it and only ever set that value to a boolean.  But that seems like overkill, especially since at that point it doesn't really matter what type it is since it's privately encapsulated anyway.